# Assigning value causes program to hang. Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, client-server

I am creating a multiplayer game that has to communicate with a server. To communicate I have made a ClientObject that continuously waits for a message from the server. When a message is received, it deciphers what it is and sends out an event with the message. In the function that fires when the event has been broadcast, I try to assign part of the message to a PlayerObject. For example, the name of the other players. My issue is that when it reaches Players[i].Name = name[i] the program hangs. Debug shows that name[i] is the expected value. Player[i].Name is null at the point of assignment but is an available String variable so the line should work.

**Client Object:**

```
public class ClientObject
{
    public Socket clientSocket;
    public void Connect()
    {
        IPEndPoint serverAddress = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.56.1"), 3000);

        clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        clientSocket.Connect(serverAddress);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceiveMessage));
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void ReceiveMessage() {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {

                byte[] rcvLenBytes = new byte[4];
                clientSocket.Receive(rcvLenBytes);
                int rcvLen = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(rcvLenBytes, 0);
                byte[] rcvBytes = new byte[rcvLen];
                clientSocket.Receive(rcvBytes);
                String rcv = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rcvBytes);



                MessageReceivedEventArgs args = new MessageReceivedEventArgs();
                args.Message = rcv;

                if (TestMessageRecevied != null)
                {
                    TestMessageRecevied(this, args);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }


    public delegate void MessageHandler(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e);
    public event MessageHandler TestMessageRecevied;
}
    public class MessageReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

}
```

**Player Object:**

```
public class PlayerObject
{

    public string Name 
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool ReadyState
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int DiceLeft
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

**Ready Menu:**

```
public class ReadyMenu : MonoBehaviour
{

    ClientObject client;

    public GameObject backgroundPanel;
    public Sprite tick;
    public Sprite cross;

    Text pName;
    Image imgCheck;

    PlayerObject[] players;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        pName = GameObject.Find("PlayerPanel1/Name").GetComponent<Text>();

        players = new PlayerObject[6];
        client = new ClientObject();
        client.TestMessageRecevied += Client_MessagedReceived;
        client.Connect();
        SendClientMessage(PlayerPrefs.GetString("name"));

    }

    private void Client_MessagedReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Log("In C_MR: " + e.Message);
        string message = e.Message;

        if (message.Contains("READY"))
        {
            //NOT IMPLEMENTED YET
            Debug.Log("contains ready");

            //message = message.Substring(5);
            //int pId = message[0] - '0';
            //int rV = message[1] - '0';
            //if (rV == 1)
            //{
            //    readyCheck[pId] = true;
            //}
            //else 
            //{
            //    readyCheck[pId] = false;
            //}
            return;
        }
        if (message.Contains("PLAYERS"))
        {
            //Message before split
            Debug.Log(message);
            message = message.Substring(7);

            //Cut PLAYERS from the string
            Debug.Log("substring: "+message);

            //Seperate names
            char[] sep = { ' ' };
            String[] names = message.Split(sep,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            Debug.Log("after name split");
            Debug.Log("names length is: "+names.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++) 
            {

                Debug.Log("in loop, i = "+i);

                Debug.Log("in loop, setting playerobject name");
                players[i] = new PlayerObject();
                players[i].Name = names[i];
                Debug.Log("in loop, after setting playerobject name");

                //GameObject panel = GameObject.Find("PlayerPanel" + (i + 1));
                //Debug.Log("in loop, activate apnel");
                //panel.SetActive(true);
            }
            Debug.Log("finsihed");
        }

    }
```

**Output with the name being test**

In C_MR: PLAYERStest

PLAYERtest

Substring: test

after split

names length is: 1

in loop, i = 0

in loop, setting playerobject name

Comment: Is `players[i]` null? You're instantiating an array of size 6 but I don't see you creating the players anywhere in the code posted. Without that its just an array of null references. You'll need to iterate through the array and make sure you instantiate a `new PlayerObject()` for each array entry. You should have seen a `NullReferenceException` in your debug logs

Comment: Initially it had `players[i] = new PlayerObject()` within the loop, this was just another variation after trying to fix it. No errors or exceptions are thrown in the debug. It is only the Logs I print upto _in loop, setting playerobject name_

Comment: What happens if you remove the `try-catch`, as it may mask errors (in particular as you're not outputting potential errors in the catch)? And what is the purpose of your `while(true)`, and what is its break condition which guarantees you won't run into a stack overflow?

Comment: The `try-catch` is needed because of the use of a thread. There's a compilation error stating it must be surrounded by a one. The `while(true)` is a place holder until I make a variable to stop once the game is down/a player loses their lives. At the moment the client object hangs on the `clientSocket.Receive()` for a message to be received so a stack overflow issue at this point is unlikely. As this intentional hang is within an object and its own thread, this, to my knowledge should not have an affect on the function in `ReadyMenu`

Comment: @Joosh If you can't downright remove the try-catch, then [have its catch actually show the errors thrown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch) -- otherwise you'd mask them and miss crucial information. Furthermore, until you know exactly what's up, give your `while` loop some kind of forced break condition, e.g. count up to 10 and then escape it.